# How to create a link using div Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, hyperlink

I believe this is a fairly simple question but it is something I am struggling with a little. I currently have the following:

```
 <% @jobs.each do |f| %>
   <div class="job">                
    <div class="job-desc"><%= f.company %> are looking for a <%= f.job_title %>
        <div class="job-sal"><%= f.job_salary %></div>
    </div>  
    </div>
 <% end %>
```

I would like to create it so that each `job` instance is a link to that job's show page. What I can't work out is how to integrate rails' `<%= link_to "something", job_path %>`

I have tried placing the entire block of code into the "something" part in the example above but that doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly,you want the entire divs to be links? If that is the case, please try the following:

```
<% @jobs.each do |job| %>
  <%= link_to job_path(job) do %>
    <div class="job">                
      <div class="job-desc"><%= job.company %> are looking for a <%= job.job_title %>
        <div class="job-sal"><%= job.job_salary %></div>
      </div>  
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I'd suggest having a look at it in rails API doc. http://api.rubyonrails.org/